# Difference in output for a logic written with function and not with func

Tags: python-3.x

I have word file from http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt and while writing a simple logic to find words that have letter ('a','e','i','o','u') and one that doesn't have i tried describing a simple function which would print result for one word only not entire set and writing the same logic without defining function worked, could you please explain

```
def avoid():
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for i in fin:
        word = i.strip()
        for x in word:
            if x in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
                return False
        return True 
fin = open('words.txt')
for i in fin:
    word = i.strip()
    for x in word:
        if x in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
            print ('False')
        else:
            print('True')
```

The latter part worked while the former logic yield only one word result.

Comment: in function you use return - that exits the function - in the later code you just use print

Comment: yes because that gave some output could you please explain why the former part failed to give only one output for the data set

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to consider functions as subprograms. As bhaskarc noted, your function enters. You want the non-function behavior, i.e. go trough the file and for each word in the file do something. If you write it in a function as you did, your subprogram (your function) will stop and return the result only for the first word, and because it **always returns** a result, it will never be able to process the rest of the file.

What you (probably) want to do is, either:

1. Modify your `avoid()` function, so that you make start with some empty results list, and append the result of each word to that list, and in the and return all the results in it. Or...
2. Write a function which returns true or false for only one word, i.e. write only the `if x in ('a','e','i','o','u'): return False; else return` in a function and call that in your loop.